# Ubuntu Phone with USB Keyboard - Howto change external keyboard layout to German?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout

On my Ubuntu Phone Aquaris E4.5 I connected a wireless keyboard with a USB receiver module.
Like I show in my German YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSYxwHMElbM 
But the the keyboard is a German one and the settings of the Ubuntu Phone is for a English keyboard.

How can I change the keymap for the external keyboard?

Comment: The question could be extended to the USB keyboard which layout is not configurable neither...

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed with OTA-10. One can now configure the art of layout of the BT keyboard.

Comment: Sounds nice, but it isn't,  because it will not work in all applications.
If I change it, it will work in the standard browser, but in Firefox it is still the English layout and in Open Office it's the English layout too.