# UK QWERTY keyboard and Spanish tilded chars in Ubuntu touch (OTA-10)

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch

I have an external BT keyboard with layout UK QWERTY

[image: layout]

which works fine with my Ubuntu mobile devices. What I in addition want to have available are the Spanish tilded chars like áéíóñ¿¡ ...

In my FreeBSD netbook I configure this at the X11 level with
commands like this which are fired up when the desktop comes up, here as
an example for the character ñ Ñ:

```
# we use the Win-key to add more (esp. Spanish) letters to the keys:
#
xmodmap -e "keycode 0x73 =  Mode_switch"
xmodmap -e "keycode 0x39 =  n N ntilde Ntilde"
```

i.e. the useless key <kbd>Win</kbd> is redefined as a X11-modifier key and pressing the keys <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> together gives just ñ.

How could I do this within the Ubuntu touch OTA-10?

Please note: we are not talking here about defining a new keyboard layout for the on-screen-keyboard, but about an existing **external** Bluetooth keyboard and how to define with some modifier key characters which are not on the keyboard itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new keyboard layout to Ubuntu Touch?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602690/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-to-ubuntu-touch)

Comment: Really related is this question: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/616505/ubuntu-phone-with-usb-keyboard-howto-change-external-keyboard-layout-to-german]

Answer (score 1):

The keymapping for terminal-app can be defined in a file `default.keytab` (exact location see below). I got working nearly all the Spanish tilded chars with the add-ons to this file as attached at the end of this answer. One problem remains: there is a key on the keyboard labeled with the `?` and `/` symbols (on a QWERTY the rightmost key on the second row next to a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key). My ideas was to produce together with Alt the char ¿ (questionmarkdown), but I do not know how the physical key is named in QT in the file `qnamespace.h` from where the key-names are derived. I tried

```
key Slash
key Question
```

both have no visible effect.

**Note**: This only works for the **terminal-app** and not for the Mir server, i.e. the other apps.

new lines in `default.keytab`

```
# added for Spanish tilded chars
# to be placed in:
# /userdata/system-data/opt/click.ubuntu.com/com.ubuntu.terminal/0.7.190/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/QMLTermWidget/kb-layouts/default.keytab
#
key A -Alt-Shift : "a"
key A -Alt+Shift : "A"
key A +Alt-Shift : "\xc3\xa1"
key A +Alt+Shift : "\xc3\x81"
#
key N -Alt-Shift : "n"
key N -Alt+Shift : "N"
key N +Alt-Shift : "\xc3\xb1"
key N +Alt+Shift : "\xc3\x91"
#
key E -Alt-Shift : "e"
key E -Alt+Shift : "E"
key E +Alt-Shift : "\xc3\xa9"
key E +Alt+Shift : "\xc3\x89"
#
key I -Alt-Shift : "i"
key I -Alt+Shift : "I"
key I +Alt-Shift : "\xc3\xad"
key I +Alt+Shift : "\xc3\x8d"
#
key U -Alt-Shift : "u"
key U -Alt+Shift : "U"
key U +Alt-Shift : "\xc3\xba"
key U +Alt+Shift : "\xc3\x9a"
#
key O -Alt-Shift : "o"
key O -Alt+Shift : "O"
key O +Alt-Shift : "\xc3\xb3"
key O +Alt+Shift : "\xc3\x93"
#
key 1 -Alt-Shift : "1"
key 1 -Alt+Shift : "!"
key 1 +Alt-Shift : "\xc2\xa1"  # 'exclamationdown'
key 1 +Alt+Shift : "\xc2\xbf"  # 'questiondown' but gives \x1b\x21
#
key 2 -Alt-Shift : "2"
key 2 -Alt+Shift : "\x22"
key 2 +Alt-Shift : "\xc2\xbf"  # 'questiondown'
key 2 +Alt+Shift : "2"         # but gives \x1b\x22
```